# How can i change Magento inventory settings to website scope instead of global?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento, inventory

We have a multi-store setup with magento operating across multiple domains.
Some of these websites are wholesale b2b websites and some are retail b2c websites.

We have a different price per retail and wholesale websites (which was easy to do in magento config) we do this as we force wholesale customers to purchase in multiples by using the magento minimum allowed in cart and must be bought in multiples inventory features. However we cannot seem to switch this off for the retail stores.

We would also like to allow backorders on wholesale website but not on the retail ones and this setting is also set to global and we cannot change it to website.

We have found several extensions that do multi-inventory (built for multiple locations etc) but these do not seem to do these inventory functions or are way too bloated for us. we only use 1 inventory we just need to switch 'allow backorders', 'minimum allowed in cart' and 'must be bought in multiples' to website scope instead of global.

Can someone please help with this. If we need to create and module and you can do it/help to do it we would be happy to pay for your services.

We are using Magento CE 1.7

Thanks

Comment: If you are refering to product detail settings in Inventory tab, then, this change is not simple, because you need the whole bloated multi-inventory stuff... there is no code in Magento to cover website specific scope through the whole process (add to cart, checkout, order management and so on)..

Comment: Hi @VEO, did you have any progress on this one?

Answer (score 1):

There's no simple solution. You can create new attributes instead of default stock attributes and override methods to use them on website level. So you need to develop small extension.